# Best practice to pass input values and variables to POST?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'll try and keep it succinct.
I am using Stripe JS to process payments.
The code for my form below:

```
<form id="payment-form" action="components/charge.php" method="POST" onSubmit={this.submitFormHandler.bind(this)}>
    <div id="payment-errors" className="payment-errors"></div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input className="first-name" id="first_name" type="text" size="50" autoComplete="off" data-stripe="first_name"/>
    <input className="card-number" type="text" size="20" autoComplete="off" />
    <input className="card-cvc" type="text" size="4" autoComplete="off" />
    <input className="card-expiry-month" type="text" size="2" />
    <input className="card-expiry-year" type="text" size="4" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" className="submit" value="Submit Payment" />
</form>
```

The code that processes the form and charges the user below:

```
if (!error) {
    // Get the Stripe token:
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
    }, function(status, response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response.error) {
            this.reportError(response.error.message);
        } else { // No errors, submit the form.
            // Get a reference to the form:
            var paymentForm = $("#payment-form");
            // Get the token from the response:
            var token = response.id;
            // Add the token to the form:
            paymentForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="' + token + '" />');
            paymentForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="' + firstName + '" />');
            // Submit the form:
            paymentForm.get(0).submit();
        }
    });
 }
```

I've included `paymentForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="' + firstName + '" />');` to save the `first_name` input value so that when I charge the user I can see further user info.
I've shortened it, the full version has address, post code, email, etc.

charge.php code below:

```
 <?php
 require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(<MY_KEY_HERE>);
 $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];

 try{
     \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(<MY_KEY_HERE>);
     $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
         "source" => $token,
         "description" => "description here",
         "email" => "tester@testemail.com",
         "shipping" => array(
             "name" => "test",
             "address" => array(
                "line1" => "123 Fake St",
                "city" => "Melbourne",
                "country" => "Australia",
                "postal_code" => "6969"
             )
          )
       )
    );
    // Charge the Customer instead of the card
    \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => 1500, // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "aud",
        "description" => "tester@tester",
        "customer" => $customer->id
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    echo  "Your card has been declined";
}
?>
```

This logic works and adds the customer and charges them as expected. I just don't know if the method to save the `first_name` input value is the best practice. I've tried to add the input value in the `Stripe.card.createToken` function, but it doesn't work, I get an undefined variable in the `POST` process.

I can't find another way to post input values / variables to `POST`.

What is best practice to `POST` input values and variables?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a `first_name` parameter as an argument to [`Stripe.card.createToken`](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#card-createToken) as this call expects no such argument. (There is an optional `name` argument for the full cardholder's name.)

The simplest way to send a (non-PCI sensitive) field to your server would be to add a `name` attribute to the field so that it gets submitted to your server, without you having to recreate it as a hidden field.

Basically:

1. The non-card related input fields should have a `name="..."` attribute. The card related input fields should *not* (otherwise they'd get submitted to your server, negating the purpose of tokenization and making you ineligible for [PCI SAQ A](https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines)).
2. In the form's submit handler, create the token using Stripe.js and add the token as a hidden field to the form.
3. Submit the form. The browser will send every named field to the form's `action` URL.